# Show that the analytical solution of a PDE is equal to a given Wave Equation

Tags: differential-equations

I am only stuck on how to do the first part of the question, in the photo.

If someone can help me break-through this, I really appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are in the right forum? This one is about the Mathematica program and the Wolfram language. Perhaps you were looking for https://mathematics.stackexchange.com?

Comment: You are absolutely right, as this is the first part of a question about programming in Mathematica, I have been wondering around for few hours on how to code this. Where in fact, it doesn't need any coding! You just have to show what it has asked for. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Simply set `f[x-c t]` in the equation and convince yourself that this function fulfills the equation:

```
D[f[x - c t], {t, 2}] == c^2   D[f[x - c t], {x, 2}]
(*True*)
```

Of course you can do this easily by hand.